# How to store long paragraphed text in web service

Tags: ios, web-services, parse-platform

I'm making and application to show a news bulletin, so once you click the table cell of a certain new, it will present the details of the new with its paragraph. I'm using parse.com for the backend, but i don't know if pasting the whole text on a table value  would be a good approach .

what would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will point you in the right direction:

https://www.parse.com/questions/maximum-length-for-string-type-in-parse-data-database

> There's no explicit limit on string length, but Parse Objects are
>   limited to 128k. Otherwise, you should use a Parse File.

If you are planning to have many articles and there will be a lot of data to download you probably want to store the full text separate from the PFObject that represents the article. For example, you may have a PFObject with title, date, etc, but store the full text in another PFObject or PFFile. You can then fetch the object containing the full text when a user selects an item in your tableview.